# Entity Framework 5 Complex Types

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

even if I done googlin' about that for more than hour, anyone knows if 
in EF5 a Complex Types can participate in an association?

I know till EF4.x that wasn't possible, but now? there's an official documentation statement about that?

My need is mapping a class Person with Address Complex Types which refer a City

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Address Address {get; set;}
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street {get; set;}
    public City City {get; set;}
}

public class City
{
        public int ID {get;set;}
        public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I need to do a mapping with `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` specifying the Complex Type association. It's that possible in EF5?
Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
I saw that link [complex type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382831.aspx) even if it refer to Entity Data Model, it says that it's not possible to map associations to Complex Types. It's that still true?

Answer (score 0):

Even as of Entity Framework 6, complex types cannot contain navigation properties.